# snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

when i execute this code on python it will give the SQL compilation error

```
print('creating warehouse..')
sql = 'create warehouse if not exist project_warehouse'
cs.execute(sql)
print('creating database..')
sql = 'create database if not exist project_database'
cs.execute(sql)
print('using database..')
sql = 'use database project_database'
cs.execute(sql)
print('create schema..')
sql = 'create schema if not exist project_schema'
cs.execute(sql)
print('creation completed..')
```

It will give the error message like this:

```
creating warehouse..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\sparkproject\Snowflake\logincrediential.py", line 18, in <module>
    cs.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\sparkproject\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\cursor.py", line 799, in execute
    Error.errorhandler_wrapper(self.connection, self, error_class, errvalue)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\sparkproject\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py", line 277, in errorhandler_wrapper
    error_value,
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\sparkproject\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py", line 328, in hand_to_other_handler
    cursor.errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\sparkproject\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py", line 214, in default_errorhandler
    cursor=cursor,
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 24 unexpected 'exist'.
syntax error line 1 at position 47 unexpected '<EOF>'.
```

iam excepting like:

```
creating warehouse..
```

```
creating database..
```

```
using database..
```

```
create schema..
```

```
creation completed..
```

i am excepting like this

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax error because you've forgotten the last 's' in the word "exists". And you are making the same error in all the following commands. The correct syntax:

```
print('creating warehouse..')
sql = 'create warehouse if not exists project_warehouse'
cs.execute(sql)
print('creating database..')
sql = 'create database if not exists project_database'
cs.execute(sql)
print('using database..')
sql = 'use database project_database'
cs.execute(sql)
print('create schema..')
sql = 'create schema if not exists project_schema'
cs.execute(sql)
print('creation completed..')
```